# jQuery - distinguish between programmatic event calls and user event calls

Tags: jquery

I have a jQuery event listener like so:

```
$('input[data-name="PretaxAmount"]').live('change', function () {
  ....
}
```

And I have a place in the javascript that calls this programmatically, like so:

```
pretaxAmount.change();
```

And the object "pretaxAmount" is defined thusly:

```
pretaxAmount = row.find('input[data-name="PretaxAmount"]');
```

The onchange event listener gets called both programmatically and via human interaction. I need to be able to tell the difference, so that I know when a human has triggered the event in the browser and not the javascript that has done it automatically on page load. I have seen some stackoverflow solutions on this but they don't seem to fit my particular scenario very well.

I will award the answer to a specific code sample of how to achieve this *with my code*, rather than a link to some other question or article. Thanks in advance.

Comment: First off, you should no longer be using `.live()` as it has been deprecated and then removed from recent versions of jQuery.  The dynamic form of `.on()` is the replacement.

Comment: What exactly did you try? There's not even a need to make the handler itself able to decide -- you can easily split the handler in more than one piece and manually call what you need instead of triggering the handler. It's also easy to make it able to tell by making it a named function and calling it directly with whatever arguments you want.

Comment: Did you look at the `event` passed to the handler to see what differences there are in the event when you trigger it manually?

Comment: How do I look at the event passed to the handler? I don't see a param/arg that would be the event object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to tell the difference:

```
function handlePretaxChange(e) {
    if (!e) {
        // triggered manually by code
    } else {
        // triggered by user
    }
}

$(document).on('change', 'input[data-name="PretaxAmount"]', handlePretaxChange);

// trigger in your code (assumes you only have one item named pretaxAmount):
var pretaxAmount = row.find('input[data-name="PretaxAmount"]');
handlePretaxChange.call(pretaxAmount[0], null);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about checking the existence of the originalEvent attribute?

```
var pretaxAmount = row.find('input[data-name="PretaxAmount"]');
$(pretaxAmount).change(function(e){
    if(!!e.originalEvent){
        console.log("human");
    }else{
        console.log("CPU");
    }
})
```

jQuery provides this attribute when wrapping events into its own objects.

```
pretaxAmount.change(); //prints CPU
```